# CollectionView Application crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view application (with a nav bar) where the MainViewController loads the correct "cells". When I make a selection the DetailViewController loads with the correct "cells" for a quick second and then I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[NSISRestrictedToZeroMarkerVariable
useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb024810ce0'
```

Comment: Could you add some code snippets of your cell selection and your DetailViewController. Have you tried adding the exception breakpoint to find the exact position of your error ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: I think i figured out the problem (for the most part). I have the viewcontrollers in a navigation controller and when it pushes the DetailVC it crashes.  I think it is because I never implemented a layout object because my current error is 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'.